# Segmentation by map

Tags: python, image, opencv

Goodnight,
I have a body thermo image and I need to do a segmentation based on a body map.
I am attaching the images.

[body] (https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-forum-message-attachments/536018/13283/body.jpeg)

[map] (https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-forum-message-attachments/536018/13284/map.png)

Anyone have any clue and can help-me?

I have tried to overlay the images but, how they are not perfect fit it not worked.

I expected to have a series of images, one for each region.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use deep learning technique, its Generative adversarial network (GAN) based method. you can search online, its all over the place. Search keyword: deep fake, GAN

[image]

The traditional technique is to use shiftmap based method, e.g object rearrangement using shiftmap technique.  opencv has simple for impainting/retargeting implementation you can convert this to deformable model rearrangement case

the detailed work can be found at.

http://www.vision.huji.ac.il/shiftmap/inpainting/